# Tizen TV: develop UI Testing automation

Tags: tizen, ui-testing, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

I need to develop a test automation for Tizen TV.
For now it is for web applications.
Note:
Test automation means to develop a program which sends commands from PC, such as:
 
* Simulating remote control commands
* Get the elements on the TV screen and their state 
  (in focus, displayed, enabled, ...).

Answer (score 0):

[This page from Tizen wiki](https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Common_QA) says: Currently there is no process of automated tests ready to be published.

As far as I have seen I didn't found UI Testing automation development tool specific for Tizen yet.